# Suitable model Regression, high feature, low sample, time-series

Tags: machine-learning, regression

I am trying to solve a prediction task with the following characteristics:

- High feature dimension (larger than all samples present)
- Low sample count
- Time-Series Data

My goal is to predict the target variable based on multiple independent features. How can I include the time-series information, for example in LinearRegression or AdaBoost?

My features are also available for the time point to be predicted.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to include time series data effectively is to convert the time from the raw string format to a periodic form i.e. sine and cosine form. This  form is more usable to any model you choose, since it can be easily converted to numpy array. But unfortunately it will increase your features the more because. To capture all information from the string time format it is advice to use feature discriding hour in sine and cosine separately, day and  year in sine and cosine separately. This makes additional six feature that is -

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def date_features(df):
    df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
    df['hour_sin'] = np.sin(2 * np.pi * df['date'].dt.hour / 23.0)
    df['hour_cos'] = np.cos(2 * np.pi * df['date'].dt.hour / 23.0)
    df['day_sin'] = np.sin(2 * np.pi * df['date'].dt.day / 30.0)
    df['day_cos'] = np.cos(2 * np.pi * df['date'].dt.day / 30.0)
    df['year_sin'] = np.sin(2 * np.pi * (df['date'].dt.dayofyear - 1) / 365.0)
    df['year_cos'] = np.cos(2 * np.pi * (df['date'].dt.dayofyear - 1) / 365.0)
    return df
```

Additional features should not really matter though, especially when you are using neural network (deep learning) cause it zero out less important features on optimization. But if not I feel doing some analysis on the features and choosing the once that correlate with the target will help guide against over fitting the model.

Finally I should also remind you that, since it's a time series you will be using time step -this means that training is done by stepping through the samples using the window you provide one after another (with the windowgenerator function) till you get to the end of the sample. This implies that you can't shuffle when splitting your train/dev/test set. You only split end to end to keep the time consistent